# Android - Edit SqlLite database from different activities c#

Tags: c#, android, sql, visual-studio, sqlite

I am developing a `C#` Android that takes the user input and add it to a database, then in another Activity, it displays the user input with an option to edit his input again.

So I have 2 activities and 1 public class which links them together. I am using SQLLite to save the user input into a database (in the `MainActivity.cs`) then (in the `secondActivity`) it retrieves the saved value (which is the user input) from the public database (located in the public class called `Class1`) and displays it in a `Textview`.

**Class1.cs**

```
      namespace App
  {
   public class Class1
    {
     public static string dpPath= Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
      public void Insert(string Quantity, string name)
      {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var logintable = new LoginTable();
        logintable.quantity = Quantity;
        logintable.name = name;
        db.Insert(logintable);
    }
    public void edit(string Quantity) 
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var logintable = new LoginTable();
        logintable.quantity = Quantity;
        db.Update(logintable);
    }
    public void delete(int id)
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var logintable = new LoginTable();
        logintable.id = id;
        db.Delete(logintable);
    }
    public Class1()
    {
        //Creating database, if it doesn't already exist 
        if (!File.Exists(Class1.dpPath))
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
            db.CreateTable<LoginTable>();
        }
    }
    public class LoginTable
    {

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]

        public int id { get; set; } // AutoIncrement and set primarykey  

        [MaxLength(25)]

        public string quantity { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string name { get; set; }

        public LoginTable()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
    Class1 cl = new Class1():
    cl.Insert(input.ToString(), name.ToLower());
```

**SecondActivity.cs**

```
        Class1 cl = new Class1():
        cl.edit(input.ToString());
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var table = db.Table<Class1.LoginTable>();
        foreach( var item in table) {
        textView.Text += item.name + "     " + item.quantity;
        }
```

Well, I am getting in the `textview` in the `secondActivity`, the input that was entered the first time (in the `MainActivity`) and not the one which was edited later in the `SecondActivity`. I thought that maybe because I have created two different instance of the `Class1` and each one is working with a different Table. In addition, I have tried to initialise a public static instance of the `Class1` inside the `Class1` itself like that:

> public class Class1 { public static Class1 cl = new Class1(); }

but did not work either, the `textview` is still displaying the original input and not the edited one. I need to be able to edit the database from each activitie.. Please help me to find a solution.

**UPDATE**
I have created a new class `Class2` and I have initialise  inside it a new instance of `Class1` like that:

```
    public class Class2 
    { 
          public static Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
    }
```

And then i have tried to access this instance of the class1 in the Main and second activity, so in the Main my code are:

```
      Class2.cl.Insert(input.ToString(), name.ToLower());
```

and in the second activity my code are:

```
        Class2.cl.edit(input.ToString());
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
        var table = db.Table<Class1.LoginTable>(); // The issue is in this line
        foreach( var item in table) {
        textView.Text += item.name + "     " + item.quantity;
        }
```

So now the issue I think is in the `secondActivity`, the `var table` is getting only one table which is the one where the original input in the Main activity is stored, and when updating the value in the second activity, it is not considering the second table which stores the edited input. But still i don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

On first glance it appears that your `Edit()` method is not correct. You have this:

```
public void edit(string Quantity) 
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
    var logintable = new LoginTable();
    logintable.quantity = Quantity;
    db.Update(logintable);
}
```

But you have no way to quantify which item in the database that you wish to update; you're just creating a new item and then trying to update the table with that item. You should instead add some way to select the item you wish to edit, like this example:

```
public void Edit(int id, string quantity)
{
   var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dbPath);
   var table = db.Table<Class1.LoginTable>();
   var itemToEdit = table.First(f=>f.Id == id);
   itemToEdit.quantity = quantity;
   db.Update(itemToEdit);
}
```

As you can see, the example above gets the item from your table, edits the item and updates your table with the data you gave it.

Your `Delete()` method should follow a similar path, instead of instantiating a new object just to delete it.

Also about your update, you should consider researching the Singleton pattern. Here is a better way to handle a static object than your `Class1/Class2` implementation. In your `Class1` class, add the field:

```
public static readonly Class1 Instance = new Class1()
```

And then reference your instance from other classes like this:

```
Class1.Instance.Insert(input.ToString(), name.ToLower());
```

This way there is no way for you to accidentally create a new instance of Class1.

Comment: `var itemtoedit = table.First(f => f.id == id);` I've got an exception in this line: `System.InvalidOperationException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`. Plus, this static readonly instance is not working, I am getting an unhandled exception with no details when executing.

Comment: @Wassim01 The `System.InvalidOperationException` is due to the `First()` not finding a matching item in the table. You should try printing out both the table contents and the id passed to `Edit()` to narrow down the search. I cannot comment on the `static readonly instance` without any details on the exception. Maybe you could use Try/Catch blocks to print out the exception so I have more to work with.